# jQuery sortable own element as placeholder

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm implementing a connected list like a Kanban board. Everything works but the placeholder is still missing. I'm looking now for a way to add a the own element as placeholder like how they done it in Gitlab:

[image]

How can I do this? I know that there is a placeholder variable but I'm not sure how I can use the same element as placeholder. This is my code:

```js
jQuery( document ).ready( function ( $ ) {
  $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

```css
#sortable1, #sortable2 {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    width: 142px;
    min-height: 20px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  #sortable1 li, #sortable2 li {
    margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    width: 120px;
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
</ul>
 
<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 5</li>
</ul>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: give value on each li like numbers and sort based on those numbers.

Comment: What? I don't understand what you mean. I'm talking about placeholders and not searching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does something like this help you?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    start: function(event, ui) {
      var clone = $(ui.item[0].outerHTML).clone();
    },
    placeholder: {
      element: function(clone, ui) {
        return $('<li class="fade">' + clone[0].innerHTML + '</li>');
      },
      update: function() {
        return;
      }
    },
  }).disableSelection();

});
```

```css
#sortable1,
#sortable2 {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  width: 142px;
  min-height: 20px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 0 0 0;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#sortable1 li,
#sortable2 li {
  margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  width: 120px;
}

.fade {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
  </ul>

  <ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 5</li>
  </ul>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That helped me, thanks! But never declare a variable implicity. Maybe you should change this in your answer. Thanks for the idea with the clone!